# Connecting to WSO2 identity server entitlement service through Java Request sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to connect to the WSO2 identity server entitlement service through Java code using Jmeter Java Request sampler. Whenever I run my test plan (which has only a java request sampler pointing to my test class) I get the following error:

```
014/01/25 17:27:21 ERROR - com.medi.sample.webapp.client.EntitlementServiceClient: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v4 - file:/Users/narimanammar/NetBeansProjects/apache-jmeter-2.10/lib/ext/axis2-1.6.1-wso2v4.jar 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault) caught when processing request: Connection closed by remote host 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault) caught when processing request: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault) caught when processing request: Connection closed by remote host 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request 
2014/01/25 17:27:21 INFO  - org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender: Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://localhost:9444/services/EntitlementService] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection closed by remote host
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:449)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub.EntitlementServiceStub.getDecision(EntitlementServiceStub.java:206)
```

Comment: It's nothing with JMeter, check your Java code logic as it looks like that you're trying to feed to server something, it's unable to parse as per `Invalid argument` error message

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, you may be right. I actually  parse a request that is coming from a CSV file then I am investigation it further in the code. However, still this does not justify the Axis fault exception. Right?!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see any error in the WSO2 IS console (or wso2carbon.log file which can be found at /repository/logs directory)? I guess you are calling entitlement service via web application? If you want to directory do some load test on entitlement service you can use [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/10/15/xacml-pdp-performance-testing/) details. Entitlement service is a just a web service (secured with Basic auth). you can use any web service client to invoke this service.

Comment: Hello Asela, the issue is I need to do further investigation after I get the response from PDP/WSO2IS entitlement service. Therefore, I need to do the whole request handling logic inside the code. I am indeed using a PEP client code that I found on the website that you sent.  I feel that the issue is with handling this certificate thing through Jmeter java request sampler. I ran into this certificate issue when I ran the client code in NetBeans and I fixed it also in the code. But now there is another axis fault exception.

Comment: Asela, regarding your first question, NO there are no issues in the WSO2 server console or log file. I don't think that the error is on WSO2 side as i get a confirmation "login successful" message each time a request arrives.

Comment: And regarding the technique that you sent I believe I can't use SOAP request samplers since I need to do further investigation after I get the response from PDP/WSO2IS entitlement service. Is there a way to use those samplers and to still do the validation after getting the result from WSO2? Please advise a test plan that does that? Thank you.

Comment: Normally WSO2 Identity Server's certificate must be set in your client's trust store file. But here,  it is generated different error (not the one that you mentioned above)... I am not sure about above error. Is this error generated from  your client that you have written? I have seen some "Invalid argument" error when calling to entitlement service when the client is in MAC OS. Ar u using MAC OS?

Comment: You can do result validation in jmeter by using response assertions. AS an example, you can just check for "Permit" String in the XACML response.   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion

Comment: Hello,I am using a MAC OS. When I try the client code in NetBeans it works perfectly fine. No argument exceptions or any other exceptions. In Jmeter the Assertion is not doing me any good since I don't get to the point where I get any responses through (Jmeter GUI). It seems that the exception occurs while processing the JavaRequest, i.e., while runing the test class. Is there a way I can debug further and see the reason before I get to Jmeter?

Comment: In the response data tab I get: java.lang.Exception: Error while evaluating with PDP at XX.EntitlementServiceClient.getDecision()...

Comment: I think the issue is with the load. I tried with only 5 threads and reduced the number of rows in the CSV file (from which my java code loads requests) to 10. Now I am not getting errors. I still need to fix the tester to handle more than that.